# Redundant index number in Pandas - can I disable it?

Tags: python, pandas

is it feasible to strip a redundant index returned by groupby in pandas?

So in the following example using iris datasets:

```
df.groupby(["Species"]).apply(lambda x: x[x["Sepal.Length"]>=6]["Petal.Length"] + x[x["Petal.Length"]>=4]["Sepal.Width"])
```

This returns Series, but unfortunately it has an awful index along with the grouped variable.

And note that I cannot strip it afterward, since the actual computation is much more convoluted such as:

```
 df.groupby(["Species"]).apply(lambda x: x[x["Sepal.Length"]>=6]["Petal.Length"] + x[x["Petal.Length"]>=4]["Sepal.Width"])
```

, which returns lots of NAN.

Note that the actual datasets I use don't have NAN values within the lambda function (i.e. at least one record meets x[x["Sepal.Length"] >= 6 and x[x["Petal.Length"] >= 4] for all grouped variables, so it shouldn't return NAN. And I found out that the reason it still returns NAN is because of the redundant indexes.

Also, in this case:

```
df.groupby(["Species"]).apply(lambda x: x["Sepal.Length"].mean())
```

the result of this execution doesn't include the redundant indexes - why?

So I want to disable the useless feature within the lambda function. Is it feasible?

Comment: What have you tried. Did you see the `groupy_keys` keyword in groupby? `group_keys : boolean, default True
    When calling apply, add group keys to index to identify pieces`.

For your second question, I think that's because you're actually doing an aggregation: `.mean()` returns one value per group.

Comment: You don't get what I'm asking here. I tried `group_keys` and `as_index`, but those are related to the grouping variable itself (i.e. removing `Species` or not here). What I'd like to strip away here is the redundant numerical index, not the grouping variable.